# Equaivalent of IE autocomplete=off in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Is there an equivalent of the autocomplete="off" parameter for HTML input fields that works with Chrome?

Out site takes credit cards but Chrome remembers previously entered numbers an is killing our PCI compliance

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191

Answer (score 2):

`autocomplete=off` should work if you set it on the `<form>` element and it's there before the page finishes loading. For users, I recommend installing the [`autocomplete=on` Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh) to reverse the annoying `autocomplete=off`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem but i used autocomplete=off on master page  tag. Then all auto completed fields removed from project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in your tag as well the input tag where the user enters the data

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<input type="text" style="width:350px" class="form-control" id="email_id" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by Name or Email Address"  />
```

this works fine in Chrome.

You can also use it in form

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" autocomplete="off">
//Your Code Here.
</form>
```

Hope this helps.